# Minimum order amount by customer segment

Tags: magento2, cart

I would like to be able to create the conditions for the cart:
Minimum quantity
Minimum amount
According to customer segments.
Each customer segment will have a different cart condition
Example: Minimum order in cart in remote areas will have to be larger in value and quantity

Answer (score 0):

The [Magento User Guide](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/minimum-order-qty.html) is the place to find this information. From that manual you will find:

1. Go to Stores > Settings > Configuration.
2. In the left panel, expand Catalog and choose Inventory.
3. Expand Expansion selector the Product Stock Options section.
4. For Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart, set the minimum quantity of the product for an order.
5. Click Save Config.

To further restrict the minimum quantities, you will need to write a Module. You can find more information on writing a module [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/).

Comment: Thanks so much!

But I want to create minimum cart selection by customer segments.
I want to follow the conditions in the customer segments to give the minimum cart requirements

Comment: For this you will need to create a module and override certain Magento classes. It is not a simple task. I suggest either hiring a Magento developer, or reading [the Magento Dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/) and asking **very specific** questions here when you get stuck.